# Assigning to an instance's __class__ attribute in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Under what circumstances is it possible, and when is it impossible, to assign to an instance's `__class__` attribute in Python?

Error messages such as `TypeError: __class__ assignment: only for heap types` don't really do it for me.

Comment: @Rafe: actually, Django uses this trick in its authentication code

Comment: late to the party, but matplotlib does this in production code too (in some of the 3D plotting).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can only assign to the `__class__` attribute of an instance of a user-defined class (i.e. defined using the `class` keyword), and the new value must also be a user-defined class.  Whether the classes are new-style or old-style does not matter. (You can't mix them, though. You can't turn an old-style class instance into a new-style class instance.)  See also [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue4600) in the Python bug tracker, which also complains that the error message is somewhat hard to understand.

Just to add what Rafe said in the above comment: **Never do this in production**.

Comment: Also, from my experimenting it seems that the presence/absence of `__slots__` also makes a difference: "X deallocator differs from Y" from `instance_with_slots.__class__ = ClassWithoutSlots` and `instance_without_slots.__class__ = ClassWithSlots`

Comment: Ah, I was confused because did `a.__class__ = B.__class__` when I obviously should have been doing `a.__class__ = B`

Comment: See http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg52950.html for a list of differences between types that might give troubles

Comment: Both `matplotlib` and `django` do this in production, according to the above comments

Comment: @dtheodor what a bold and frankly silly statement.  Yes,  Python chooses to expose some of its quite advanced and easy-to-misuse machinery, but *it is* a choice: `__class__` *could* have been made a read-only attribute.  Saying that these mature and exceptionally well supported projects are "doing it wrong" because they do something that we advise newcomers against on stackoverflow is like saying that engineers are doing it wrong because they're not using sliderules, or space shuttle welders doing it wrong because they're not using soldering irons.

Comment: @jedwards Not everything that language designers allow to do is actually a good idea, even if popular projects do it.  I don't have the time to write a detailed analysis, but after looking at the code it is my conviction that both Django and Matplotlib would be better off not using this hack.  It's too much magic for virtually no gain.