# Changing the type of each dictionary in a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, function, dictionary, scope

In an existing python script I use vivification for work with dictionary of dictionaries.

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
        """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(AutoVivification, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.vivify = True
                self.root = self

        def __getitem__(self, item):

                try:
                        return dict.__getitem__(self, item)

                except KeyError:
                        if not self.root.vivify:
                                raise
                        value = self[item] = type(self)()
                        value.root = self.root
                        return value

        def unvivify(self):
                self.vivify = False

        def revivify(self):
                self.vivify = True

        def upgrade(self):
                self.root = self
```

I would like apply this class for each dictionary in a dictionary of dictionaries. I thought to something like that:

```
def upvivification(dico):
        """Upgrade to the last autovivification version."""

        if isinstance(dico, dict):
                dico = AutoVivification(dico)

                for k in dico:

                        if isinstance(dico[k], dict):
                                upvivification(dico[k])
```

But, indeed it is not working because the scope of this change is in the function and not global ... I do not see how to recursively make this change ...

Comment: What is **change** in *"scope of this change is in the function"*? Do you mean to update the `dico` dict passed as argument?

Comment: Also, is `upvivification` function is within `AutoVivification` class or outside it?

Comment: Yes it is to update the dico passed as argument.

Comment: The upvivification function is outside of AutoVivification class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return dico in the end and reassign the return value in your recursive call:

```
def upvivification(dico):
    if isinstance(dico, dict):
        dico = AutoVivification(dico)
            for k in dico:
                if isinstance(dico[k], dict):
                    dico[k] = upvivification(dico[k])
        return dico
```

Then use like:

```
some_dict = upvivification(some_dict)
```

It is only possible to change the `type` of an existing object mutation-style with great [pain and care](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838145/assigning-to-an-instances-class-attribute-in-python). You can, however, reassign the old variable to the new object.

Comment: Oh great !!!! Exactly what I looked for ... and I think I need to sleep ... thanks a lot ....

Answer (score 1):

```
def upvivification(dico):
        """Upgrade to the last autovivification version."""

        if isinstance(dico, dict):
                dico = AutoVivification(dico)

                for k in dico:

                        if isinstance(dico[k], dict):
                                dico[k] = upvivification(dico[k])
        return deco
```

And use it like

```
new_dico = upvivification(dico)
```

Comment: Oh great !!!! Exactly what I looked for ... and I think I need to sleep ... thanks a lot ....